# RODBC (SQL Server) giving inconsistent results for long character fields converted to numeric

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I'm using RODBC to extract data from a MSSQL Database, and I'm getting inconsistent results.

One column is defined in SQLServer as below:

```
Column_name         Type    Computed    Length  Nullable TrimTrailingBlanks FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
Mycolumn            varchar no          50      yes     no      yes   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I'm trying to extract the data with:

```
cn <- odbcConnect("mybase", uid=user, pwd=pswd)
bad_planned_calls <- sqlQuery(cn, "select id, mycolumn from mytable where date_time between '2018-05-04' and '2018-05-04 23:59:59' and client= 'client'")
odbcClose(cn)
```

When I print the query with `print(qry)` and drop that into SQL Server Management Studio I'm getting the expected results (a column 4 different character values (all numbers) of 18 characters).

What I get with the RODBC query is one of the 4 results (18 digits in length, stored as num in r). NAs are in the correct places, but only one value is repeated, like below:

```
Incorrect (in R-Studio, and RGui):
id            mycolumn
RC-TTT-033555 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033374 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033930 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033943                  NA
RC-TTT-033560 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033938 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033944                  NA
RC-TTT-033622 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033543 4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033559 4331067215106222606

Correct (using printed sql statement from R in SSMS):
RC-TTT-033555   4331067215106222786
RC-TTT-033374   4331067215106222441
RC-TTT-033930   4331067215106222786
RC-TTT-033943   
RC-TTT-033560   4331067215106222546
RC-TTT-033938   4331067215106222786
RC-TTT-033944   
RC-TTT-033622   4331067215106222441
RC-TTT-033543   4331067215106222606
RC-TTT-033559   4331067215106222786
```

Why is this happening? Note I have run `options(scipen = 20, digits = 20)`

I'm open to suggestions on how to make this more reproducible, thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Note: I've also checked the results using pyodbc and pandas in python, and the results are consistent with SSMS.

Comment: Forget RODBC. String concatenation means SQL injection *and* conversion errors. The query itself is the bug. Storing *numbers* as `nvarchar` is another very serious bug. If you want to store numbers, store numbers with the desired scale and precision using the `decimal` or synonymous `numeric` type

Comment: As for the values themselves, the same query over the same data will return the same results. If they are different, check your code. The database drivers don't kick or mix up results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I'm not concerned about the Injection side of things, in this case it will not be relevant, as it's for a script used by me alone.  As for storing numbers as strings, i thought this was standard practice with the possibility of leading 0s.

Comment: You should be. The same type of bug will mangle the date **strings** you passed and try to parse them using a localized format. The same bug could convert numbers to strings using the wrong local. And no, storing numeric data as strings it's definitely NOT standard practice, especially when precise decimal types or big integer types are readily available.

Comment: As for your problem, the ODBC driver doesn't change the results. If the results change, it's either because the *data* changed or because you read the results in the wrong way. The *RODBC* package could have a bug, but the query is so simple that this seems unlikely. *All* queries return NULLs after akk How did you print out the results? How did you determine the results are bad the first time or subsequent times?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the fedback, I'll bear that in mind.  I printed the results in Rstudio using the print command and compared them manually to results in SSMS, line by line, using the primary key in both results sets as a reference

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've rewritten my question to make it more readable and concise based on your comments.  thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried to use `as.is = TRUE` as an argument to `sqlQuery()`? It may help. Or you could also give a try to the [odbc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=odbc) package.

Comment: @Scarabee well played sir! write it in an answer if you like and the points are yours!

Comment: @User632716 Actually that's more or less a duplicate of a question I asked 2 years ago.

Comment: @Scarabee Thanks for the link, I confirmed it as a duplicate.  Much appreciate your help